# SSRS - Domain Migration and Subscription Ownership

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2017

We are in the process of migrating from one domain to another and it seems users cannot see the subscriptions they created when they were logged in using the old domain credentials.

How can I, in bulk, make the users new domain credentials able to see the old domain subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was accomplished by running this in SSMS on the ReportServer dB

```
DECLARE @OldUserID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @NewUserID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @OldUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'old_domain\user'
SELECT @NewUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'newdomain\user'
UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @NewUserID WHERE OwnerID = @OldUserID
```